# What is the proper way to both rotate and translate text in d3?

Tags: d3.js

I have an array with two strings and I want them to align with two circles (see example: http://bl.ocks.org/3028447)

I'm currently doing this:

```
.attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + x(i)+",0) rotate(-45," + x(1)+"," + 0+") "; })
```

I was sure there was a simpler way to do it, something like this:

```
.attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + x(i)+",0) rotate(-45) "; })
```

but when I use that I get this (http://bl.ocks.org/3028512), and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've combined your transform with *x* and *y* attributes:

```
.attr("y", 0)
.attr("x", 60)
```

These get applied before the transform (i.e., before the rotation), hence the text is not in the same position as the circles. Sometimes this technique is useful; the *x* moves the text parallel to the text’s baseline. So, if you wanted to position the text slightly outside the circle, you could change the *x* value to 6 rather than 60.

Comment: Hey Mike, thanks, but then I won't get the text on top of the second and third circle (I want to skip the first one). Is there a simpler way to do it than how I did it? (here's a fiddle with the same code: http://jsfiddle.net/VJvSM/

Comment: If you want the text and circles to be positioned together, then you generally want to put both of them in a G element and put the transform on the G element, rather than positioning them separately. But if you do want to position them separately, then you'd need to add the x to the transform (e.g., `"translate(" + (x(i) + 60) + ",0)"`).

Comment: That did it! Thanks. The reason  why I can't position them in the same group is that the 3 circles already belong to a group with other things, and only the second two circles have headers.

Comment: You might be able to fix that with a key function for you data join (so that your two data objects are bound to the last two circles rather than the first two), but yeah.